# Exit a running while loop written in the python shell

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, exit

```
>>> colours = []
>>> prompt ='Enter another one of your favourite colours ( type return to end):'
>>> colour = input(prompt)
Enter another one of your favourite colours(type return to end): blue
>>> colour
'blue'
>>> colours
[]
>>> while colour != ' ' :
      colours.append(colour)
      colour = input(prompt)

Enter another one of your favourite colours ( type return to end): yellow
Enter another one of your favourite colours ( type return to end): brown
Enter another one of your favourite colours ( type return to end): return
```

I am working with Python 3

Here I add the colours the user enters on prompt into the colours[] list, the problem is I am unable to exit from this loop. help me please.

I know we can just use ctrl+c but its a keyboard interrupt so I don't want to use it.

P.S - I just started learning python, don't mind if its a seems like a silly question.

Comment: How do you want to stop the loop? through a key press? a mouse click? What is wrong with ctrl+c? this might help others understand your question more. Also you could inlude a counter than after n attempts breaks the loop.

Comment: You could change the condition in the `while` to `colour != ''`. This way the loop will exit when you press Enter when prompted.

Comment: @GáborFekete: It's a `' '`, so the user will have to enter one blank.

Comment: @Matthiasnow you have to write a space, I wrote an empty string.

Comment: Part of the (usability) problem is that the prompt says to use enter while the OP' code looks for a space. Gabor's suggestion would fix that. (The opposite fix, to tell them in the prompt to type a space *and* enter, is less attractive, but basically equivalent.)

Comment: (If having a space after the opening parenthesis is acceptable, maybe attractiveness is not a factor. Sorry, couldn't resist.)

Comment: @GáborFekete this works , thanks ! I had given a space between the quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `while` condition does not match the input you expect from the user. If you want the loop to exit when the user enters the literal string `"return"`, then you should use:

```
while colour != 'return':
```

and if you want the loop to stop when the user presses the <kbd>Return</kbd> key, use the empty `''`:

```
while colour != '':
```

Given this ambiguity, you could also combine the two using `in`, and also `strip` the input to account for possible spaces:

```
while colour.strip() not in ('return', ''):
```